# How to isolate iframed messages so they don't propagate

Tags: angular, iframe, addeventlistener

I have an issue which I can't seem to pin down.  The situation is this.  I have an angular 5 application, in one of my components i have to put in an iframe to another site.  The iframe is for the purpose of credit card processing and how it works is you get an encoded url and then use that url for your iframe,  In the iframe is one input field.  The moment you finish typing the credit card number into the input field the iframed page sends a message to the parent with an encoded value that is later used to process the payment.

The issue that I'm having is that immediately after i get the message from the iframed page, my application redirects to the login page and I can't seem to pindown what is causing this.

Here is the code that is involved:

Template:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" id="cc-iframe" [src]="ccUrl"></iframe>
```

Controller:

```
this.paymentsService.getTokenizedField(this.paymentId).subscribe(response => {
    console.log('cc return url');
    console.log(response.url);
    this.ccUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(response.url);
    this.ccUrlReady = true;

    window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        let token = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log('HERES YOUR TOKEN: ', token);
    }, {capture: true, once: true});
});
```

And obviously there is all the rest of the code in my application but i can't post that all here.  I'm fairly convinced that the solution to this problem is to capture the event and stop it from bubbling up or doing the default action but so far my efforts have not worked.

I don't know what other mechanism might be causing this behavior.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on.

Turns out there was one of these somewhere else in the code:

```
window.onmessage = function(e) {
    //irrelevant code
    window.location.href = '/login/index';
    //more irrelevant code
}
```

I couldn't find it because I was only searching the codebase for "addEventListener" which I had thought was the only way to listen for messages from an iframe.